# Remove first duplicates from a 1d array while preserving later encountered values; then filter other arrays mapped by the remaining elements' indexes

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, mapping, filtering

I have three arrays

```
$firstArray = ['22','24','23','26','22','24','23','26'];
$secondArray = ['John','Smith','Mark','Steve','George','Nick','Sean','Brad'];
$thirdArray = ['A','B','D','E','F','G','H'];
```

I want to remove the first duplicates from `$firstArray` and based on the keys of the later encountered duplicates, I want to filter the other two arrays. i.e. in `$firstArray` the second duplicated elements begin from the 4th index, (4,5,6,7)

**Expected Result**

```
$newFirstArray = ['22','24','23','26'];
$newSecondArray = ['George','Nick','Sean','Brad'];
$newThirdArray = ['E','F','G','H'];
```

I used `array_unique` and `array_values` but it sort first duplicates.

Comment: Are the items in each array guaranteed to be individually unique before you start getting all duplicates? In other words, is `[/* one */ 1, 1, 2, /* two */ 1, 1, 2, /* three */ 1, 1, 2]` a possible input?

Comment: yes, it repeats only two times i.e. [/* one */ 1, 2, 3, /* two */ 1, 2, 3] and it only repeats is firstArray not in secondArray and thirdArray

Comment: @SML: It repeats only two times? So if you cut the array in half the two pieces will have the exact same values? Is this guaranteed?

Comment: @Jon , yes it will be exact same if you cut in two

Comment: You really should improve the question by offering all of this information up front. Here's something else you should explain: you mention sorting a lot, but the expected results don't look to be sorted in any way (it's the same order as the originals). What gives?

Comment: @Jon , i already mentioned the sorted arrays(expected result) here i.e. newFirstArray, newSecondArray and newThirdArray and those are different from original arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enjoy/abuse the effect that `array_flip()` has on an array containing duplicate values -- it will overwrite earlier encountered values with later encountered values.

After that, you can use three calls of `array_diff_key()` or just loop over the flipped data and access the data based on the remaining indexes.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JvAbV))

```
$new1 = [];
$new2 = [];
$new3 = [];
foreach (array_flip($firstArray) as $index) {
    $new1[] = $firstArray[$index];
    $new2[] = $secondArray[$index];
    $new3[] = $thirdArray[$index];
}
var_dump($new1, $new2, $new3);
```

---

Or you could push references into the result arrays and keep overwriting the mapped values if they are re-encountered. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QhsJf))

```
$new1 = [];
$new2 = [];
$new3 = [];
foreach ($firstArray as $index => $value) {
    if (!isset($ref[$value])) {
        $new1[] = &$ref[$value][0];
        $new2[] = &$ref[$value][1];
        $new3[] = &$ref[$value][2];
    }
    $ref[$value][0] = $value;
    $ref[$value][1] = $secondArray[$index];
    $ref[$value][2] = $thirdArray[$index];
}
var_dump($new1, $new2, $new3);
```